# why do legal descriptions of property differ from DB to DB?

Tags: usa, real-estate

So I was looking at deeds for a particular property and the legal description of a particular property is "Lot 1 Block A Lastname Subdivision". The appraisal district, however, gives a different legal description of that property: "S9928 - Lastname Sub, Block A, Lot 1, Acres 3.03".

It's clear that they match because the lastname matches as do the block and lot but the fact that they're different means that I can't just copy / paste the legal description from one database and search for it in the other database. And if "Lastname" were sufficiently generic there'd prob be nothing I could really latch onto to find the property info in the other DB.

So why do they differ in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work for an appraisal district and can say that the discrepancy between your deed record and the appraisal record comes from how the appraisal database is maintained. All real property accounts have an account number of some kind, and this can vary widely by county.

Essentially, it is because there is a lack of standard(s) and best practices around the community.

If it were in my county, the "9928" would be the first four digit subdivision code, followed by a four digit block number (ie: block A would be 0001), followed by a four digit lot number (ie: lot 1 would be 0001), followed by an optional three digit split number (ie: if lot one were split into two, the two account numbers would be identical except for the -001 and -002 suffix. if no split, it would be -000). The account would also have an accompanying short code account number that is sequential in the database, and not based upon the legal description like the long form number.

I'm not sure what "Lastname" refers to. Is that the last name of the owner?

edit: I just saw this was a fairly old question, but hopefully anyone else that has this question might gain something from it.

Comment: i dropped in the "Essentially" line, if you don't mind. if you disagree i'll take it out.

Comment: not at all, looks good! 

yeah, there is a definite lack of standards. appraisal districts are unique to Texas and I've yet to see anything that requires any standard as far as maintenance - as long as the data is there an accessible that's good. I know this isn't just Texas, it's a nationwide issue.